# How to use single View Models in MVC to display multiple model in razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am working with mvc after doing so much R&D i started this student project but now stuck at the situation where i have no any idea how can i create a viewmodel to display data from two different models.

Comment: Can u gice us some details and write some code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [help]. Your question does not contain anywhere near enough details

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions

1. Create another model that takes your 2 or multiple models as its properties
2. Use Tuples